# What is The Rails Way for requesting an alternate view of all records?

Tags: coding-style, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails app that has a list of `Products`, and therefore I have an `index` action on my `ProductsController` that allows me to see a list of them all.

I want to have another view of the products that presents them with a lot more information and in a different format -- what's The Rails Way for doing that?

I figure my main options are:

1. pass a parameter (`products/index.html?other_view=true`) and then have an `if else` block in `ProductsController#index` that renders a different view as required. That feels a bit messy.
2. pass a parameter (`products/index.html?other_view=true`) and then have an `if else` block in my view (`index.html.haml`) that renders different html as required. (I already know this is not the right choice.)
3. Implement a new action on my controller (e.g.: `ProductsController#detailed_index`) that has it's own view (`detailed_index.html.haml`). Is that no longer RESTful?

Is one of those preferable, or is there another option I haven't considered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it would be via a custom format. This is commonly done to provide mobile specific versions of pages, but I don't see why the same idea couldn't be applied here.

Register :detailed as an alias of text/html and then have `index.detailed.haml` (or .erb) with the extra information. If you need to load extra data for the detailed view you can do so within the `respond_to` block.

Then visitors to `/somecollection/index.detailed` should see the detailed view. You can link to it with `some_collection_path(:format=>'detailed')`

I'm not sure whether this is 'bettrr' than the alternatives but there is a certain logic I think to saying that a detailed view is just an alternative representation of the data, which is what formats are for.

Comment: Nice one - I didn't think of that. This would make a lot of sense if I had multiple models that required a detailed view, but in this app I only need it for Products. But I like your thinking!

Answer (score 0):

After doing some reading, I think that adding a new RESTful action (option #3 in my question) is the way to go. Details are here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

I've updated my routes.rb like this:

```
resources :products do
  get 'detailed', :on => :collection
end
```

And added a corresponding action to my `ProductsController`:

```
def detailed
    # full_details is a scope that eager-loads all the associations
    respond_with Product.full_details
end
```

And then of course added a `detailed.html.haml` view that shows the products in a the detailed way I wanted. I can link to this with `detailed_products_path` which generates the URL `/products/detailed`.

After implementing this I'm sure this was the right way to go. As the RoR guides say, if I was doing a lot of custom actions it probably means I should have another controller, but just one extra action like this is easy to implement, is DRY and works well. It feels like The Rails Way. :-)